# Simple Q about Factorisation and Computation

Tags: number-theory

I have a very naive question.

I want to compare the computational difficulty of two calculations.

Where N is large (50 digits upwards, say)...

Calc 1 - Factorise N.
Calc 2 - Multiply the primes sequentially from 2 onwards until the product is close to N.

Is calc.2 a lot easier than Calc.1 computationally or is it a similar task but just reversed?

Thanks.

(It's odd how the system re-writes my post without asking.)

Comment: "Multiply the primes sequentially from 2 onwards until the product is close to N" pretty much assumes that the number has no **powers** of primes.    If the number were, say, N= 56, 2*3= 6, 6*5= 30, 30*7= 210 so 2*3*5 is "close to N.  What has that told you?

Comment: While "Calc 1" is a well-defined task (factoring an integer $N$), the meaning of "Calc 2" is somewhat unclear.  Which primes do you have in mind?  The wording "Multiply the primes sequentially from $2$ onwards" suggests a product of distinct primes. "Until the product is close to $N$" could mean more than one thing.  Please clarify what is intended.

Comment: Thanks hardmath. Your first para is what I had  in mind for Calc 2 and 'close to N' etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient *classical* algorithm for factoring a large integer $n$ is known as [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) and has exponential complexity.

$$
\mathcal{O}_{
\rm GNFS}\left(\exp\left[ c(\log n)^{1/3} (\log \log n)^{2/3}\right] \right)
$$

the value of $c$ depends on the nature of the number $c\sim 1.5-1.9$. See [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/199612/pomerance.pdf) reference for details.

On the other hand, the problem of multiplying the prime factors has linear complexity in the number of prime distinct factors.

Factoring then is a more complex task than multiplying. [*Quantum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm) algorithms can also perform the task of factoring a number, but they can do it in a polynomial time. [Short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm)'s algorithm for instance has complexity

$$
\mathcal{O}_{\rm Shor}\left((\log n)^2(\log \log n)(\log \log \log n)\right)
$$

which is significantly faster than GNFS

Comment: I think your point here is that the complexity of multiplying the (distinct?) prime factors is generally polynomial time, while factoring $N$ is (as far as known) of exponential complexity.  On the other hand your brief response leaves room for improvement.  Some salient aspects untouched:  What is a *classical* algorithm?  (You seem to have quoted this phrase from the Wikipedia article.)  How many prime factors are to be multiplied, and what method of multiplication achieves "linear complexity" for their product?

Comment: The Answers to [this older MathOverflow Question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44207/asymptotics-of-product-of-consecutive-primes) show that the number of consecutive prime factors needed to reach $N$ is proportional to $\ln N$, so "linear" in the bits required to input $N$.  However we must also take into account the bit complexity of multiplying those primes.

Comment: @hardmath I could also add a note on quantum factorization algorithms (Shor's algorithm) if you think it will improve the answer.

Comment: Yes, that would be a nice notion to present.

Comment: Thank you for the various thoughts. I don't need to know about quantum factorisation, I'm playing with a very simple idea. Caverac notes that factoring is more complex than multiplication - and this is one question answered.  

..." the number of consecutive prime factors needed to reach N is proportional to lnN," 

Aha, Thanks. Very useful. 

I have realised that the idea I was exploring fails for reasons I hadn't spotted, but if I can tidy it up I may come back to spell it out for your comments. .